# 3D-histogram in R: some problems

Tags: r, plot

I have some data (including NA's) and I want to make a nice 3D histogram of them. More precisely, I want the following:

1. show NA's as something that one can easily see by eye
2. make a color palette so that low values are colored 'green' and high values are colored 'red'
3. the bars should be squares independent of the actual scaling of the axes

Problems/attempts to solve:

For solving 1/2) I have set the NA's to zero and I tried to color them 'black' (which does not work as expected, see below). More precisely I have created a color palette

black, black, ..., black, light green, a little darker green, ..., dark red

Problem is: the first value (which is around 6.5 and not 0 and not NA) gets colored in black as well.. which I dont want.

EDIT: sorry, just solved this problem by using

```
lengthOfColorPalette = 50
howmanyOfThemShouldBeBlack = floor((minz/maxz)*lengthOfColorPalette)-1
```

instead of

```
lengthOfColorPalette = 20
howmanyOfThemShouldBeBlack = floor((minz/maxz)*lengthOfColorPalette)
```

For solving 3) I have set the 'scale' parameter in 'hist3D' to true but this does not give the 'square scaling' I want: both axes are scaled to [0,1] (thats good) but since the x-axis consists of regular steps from 0.5 to 1.5 and the y-axis consists of values 5,7,10,15,25, the bars look a little skew.
I just want R to use the levels I give it in order to mark the ticks at the axes and ignore their relative distance.

### Problem: how to make them real squares and give them the right annotation?

Code until now:

```
library(plot3D)

set.seed(1234)
# x and y distances are not equal!
xLevels = seq(0.5, 1.5, length=10)
yLevels = c(5,7,10,15,25)


# just produce some random data
zValueFunction = function(x, y) {
  return(3*x + y)
}
z = outer(xLevels, yLevels, zValueFunction)

# set some of the entries to 'NA'
for (i in 1:10) {
  z[sample(1:nrow(z), 1), sample(1:ncol(z), 1)] = NA
}


# replace NA's by zero
z[is.na(z)] = 0

# make a color palette [0...min(z)) --> black
# [min(z), max(z)]: linearly from green to red
table_z = table(z)
minz = as.numeric(names(table_z[2]))
maxz = as.numeric(names(table_z[length(table_z)]))

lengthOfColorPalette = 50
howmanyOfThemShouldBeBlack = floor((minz/maxz)*lengthOfColorPalette)-1

r.prop.1 = rep(0, howmanyOfThemShouldBeBlack)
r.prop.2 = seq(0, 1, length=(lengthOfColorPalette-howmanyOfThemShouldBeBlack))

g.prop.1 = rep(0, howmanyOfThemShouldBeBlack)
g.prop.2 = 1 - r.prop.2

r.prop = c(r.prop.1, r.prop.2)
g.prop = c(g.prop.1, g.prop.2)

color2 = rgb(r.prop, g.prop, 0, maxColorValue=1)

# draw the histogram
titleString = "title of hist"
hist3D(xLevels, yLevels, z, theta=330, phi=40, expand=0.7, col=color2, d=1,
       ticktype="detailed", xlab=paste0("\n\n\n", "X-AXIS"), ylab=paste0("\n\n", "Y-AXIS"), zlab=paste0("\n\n", "Z-AXIS"),axes=TRUE, border="black", scale=TRUE)
title(titleString)
```

This produces:
[image]

with the problems as described above...

Thx in advance,
Fabian Werner

Comment: Are you sure the 3D histogram is the best visualization option for your data?

Comment: Absolutely not... but it was the best form of presentation from the ones that I have tried (for example, better than persp3D and a contour map).